# Indexeddb shim not initializing on page load on safari

Tags: safari, indexeddb

I am trying to use [IndexeddbShim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) in Safari(version 5.1.7) but facing some issues using it.It doesn't create the database on the first go. But works fine , when i refresh the page. Even same happens with the example website - http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/example/ . You need to refresh the page to load data. Is there any work around of this or i am using it wrong?

Below is the sample code i am using.It works fine in other browsers.

```
$.indexedDB("SampleStore", {
                "schema": {
                    "1": function(versionTransaction){
                        var store1 = versionTransaction.createObjectStore("store1", {
                            "keyPath": "store1Id",
                            "autoIncrement": false
                        });

                        var store2 = versionTransaction.createObjectStore("store2", {
                            "keyPath": "store2Id",
                            "autoIncrement": false
                        });

                        var store3 = versionTransaction.createObjectStore("store3", {
                            "keyPath": "store3Id",
                            "autoIncrement": false
                        });
                    }
                }
            }).done(function(){
                console.log("Database created and object store opened");
            });
```

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get it working? I'm having the same problem (on Safari 7). DB doesn't get defined in the initial load, but only after a refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I founded a workaround for that, First I created a dummy database and then created my actual database for the application and then it worked fine.